# How can I get callback when there is validation error in monaco JSON editor?

Tags: monaco-editor

I am implementing a metadata JSON editor using the Monaco JSON editor.  I would like to gray out my editor's "Apply" button when there are violations of validations that I have given in the schema I have defined.  Ideally, I am looking for a "listener" function in monaco.editor that gets called once when there are violations and another listener that get called once when there are no longer any violations.  If no such thing, any other functions that I can build these listeners on top of.

Any ideas?

I looked though the Monaco editor APIs for such listeners or callbacks but could not find any.  https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/modules/monaco.editor.html

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
monacoEditorRef.onDidChangeMarkers(e=> { 
    var doesModelHaveErrors = monacoEditorRef.getModelMarkers().length != 0;
    var applyElement = document.getElementById('your-id');
    applyElement.disabled = doesModelHaveErrors;
});
```